# Mocking Non-Standard Events in F# Foq

Tags: unit-testing, f#, foq

I'm new to F#, and I'm putting myself through some exercises to learn the language. The one I'm currently trying to do is to write a unit test for a custom Castle.Windsor Facility, and I am trying to Mock the Kernel to raise a "ComponentRegistered" event.

The tools I'm using are FsUnit/xUnit/Foq.

My Code:

```
let event = Event<_,_>()

let kernel = Mock<IKernel>()
    .SetupEvent(fun k -> <@ k.ComponentRegistered @>)
    .Publishes(event.Publish)
    .Create()
```

Error Message:

> Error 4   The event 'ComponentRegistered' has a non-standard type. If
>   this event is declared in another CLI language, you may need to access
>   this event using the explicit add_ComponentRegistered and
>   remove_ComponentRegistered methods for the event. If this event is
>   declared in F#, make the type of the event an instantiation of either
>   'IDelegateEvent<*>' or
>   'IEvent<*,_>'.    C:\Workbench\EvilDev\evildev.commons\Tests\EvilDev.Commons.Windsor.Tests\Auto
>   Resolver Facility Specification.fs    35  53  EvilDev.Commons.Windsor.Tests

How do I mock/trigger this sort of event from F#?

Comment: Foq has a SetupByName method which uses reflection for protected members, I'm currently investigating if there is a way to achieve this via reflection for events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of event can be specified using a [DelegateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370450.aspx):

```
let event = DelegateEvent<ComponentDataDelegate>()
let kernel = 
    Mock<IKernel>()
        .SetupEventByName("ComponentRegistered")            
        .Publishes(event.Publish)
        .Create()    
kernel.add_ComponentRegistered(fun _ _ -> 
    printf "Bingo"
)
event.Trigger([|"x";Mock.Of<IHandler>()|])
```

The add and remove handlers for the event can be discovered via reflection using the [Type.GetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7k6k1z6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

I have extended the Foq API to allow events to be specified by name, so that you can specify the event name (untyped) to workaround the non-standard event type compiler error.

The [change set](https://foq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/475613a0810b) to add the new SetupEventByName method has been committed. If you need this right now you can either build from source or simply add the latest [Foq.fs](https://foq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foq/Foq.fs) to your project. This feature will be in Foq 1.5 which I will try and push in the next day or so.

Comment: Great, fantastic! Appreciate your effort on this.