# F# Reactive subscribe to non-standard events from COM

Tags: events, f#, com, system.reactive, com-interop

I have a native COM library (which I can modify), and I have an F# application trying to consume an event with Rx, from an Interop library, referenced in the project.

```
let events = obj :?> _IInteropEvents_Event
let disposable = 
    Observable.take 1 events.ComEventArrived
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun sender data -> ()) // sender : ISender, data : IData
```

The error message here, which I don't fully understand, is:

> The event 'ComEventArrived' has a non-standard type. If this event is
>   declared in another CLI language, you may need to access this event
>   using the explicit add_ComEventArrived and remove_ComEventArrived
>   methods for the event. If this event is declared in F#, make the type
>   of the event an instantiation of either 'IDelegateEvent<*>' or
>   'IEvent<*,_>'.

I don't mind using `add_ComEventArrived` but I can't figure out how to make this work with `Observable`

Curiously, `ComEventArrived` has 2 arguments of internal interop types, if I try to subscribe to other events that simply marshal an IUnknown, it works and I get no "non-standard type" error:

```
let events = obj :?> _ISnapshotEvents_Event
let disposable = 
    Observable.take 1 events.SnapshotEventArrived
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun sender -> ()) // sender : IUnknown (unit)
```

How can I do any of the following to solve the issue?

1. Modify COM library to fix the non-standard event type error.
2. Use explicit add_/remove_ functions with Observer.take/Observer.subscribe.
3. Other ways of firing an event *n* times before unsubscribing, without using mutable/lock.

I have read so far:

- [SO: 20819860](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819860/mocking-non-standard-events-in-f-foq)
- [SO: 31896881](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896881/how-to-properly-observe-non-standard-events)
- [SO: 41439213](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439213/f-only-do-one-action-once-for-the-first-event-without-mutability-locking)
- [Throttling F# events](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Throttling-FSharp-Events-using-the-Reactive-Extensions.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about COM interop specifically, but I can give an example of turning non-standard event into `IObservable`, which should cover your second point.

An example of non-standard event is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` where the event handler needs to return `Assembly` rather than returning `unit`. To wrap it into `IObservable` using the `add_` and `remove_` functions, you can write:

```
let assemblyResolve = 
  { new IObservable<_> with
      member x.Subscribe(observer) =
        let handler = ResolveEventHandler(fun o a -> 
          let mutable res = None 
          observer.OnNext((o, a, fun a -> res <- Some a))
          res.Value )
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve(handler)
        { new IDisposable with
            member x.Dispose() = 
              AppDomain.CurrentDomain.remove_AssemblyResolve(handler) } }
```

We create a new implementation of `IObservable` using an F# object expression. In the `Subscribe` member, we create a `ResolveEventHandler` and add it using `add_AssemblyResolve`. The result of `Subscribe` is `IDisposable` implementation that then unregisters the event handler using `remove_AssemblyResolve`.

The ugly hack here is that the `OnNext` function of an observer cannot return anything, so we instead give it a three-element tuple with the arguments and also a function that sets the return value (this is specific for `AssemblyResolve`, so I don't suspect you'll need something like this).

Comment: Hi Tomas, thank you for your answer. This indeed works and lets me subscribe to the observable! But it does mean I would have to wrap each non-standard event into a new IObservable, with different add_/remove_ and OnNext return values. Is it possible to have a more generic solution? Thank you.

Comment: I think so - if your events take the same number of arguments, you can define a function that takes `add` and `remove` as two arguments and calls those - instead of calling specific `add_AssemblyResolve`.

Comment: I knocked up a function to take add/remove as arguments. While this works fine, not all events have the same amount of args. I would ideally like to drill down to the problem of some events being defined as non-standard by the COM interop. Thanks to you, I can at least carry on with the rest of the app!